# How can I hook into tcsh's TAB completion on Linux

Tags: linux, tab-completion, tcsh

I have some directories with a number of "hidden" files. One example of this is I'm in a source controlled sandbox and some of the files have not been checked out yet.

When I hit TAB, I'd like the option of seeing these files.

A similar question has been asked before: [CVS Tab completion for modules under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212994/cvs-tab-completion-for-modules-under-linux)
The answers to that question summarize to: "Ubuntu's got that built in".

I don't have the option of switching to Ubuntu, but surely I can use the same mechanisms.

1. how can I hook into the TAB-completion feature of tcsh to add additional file Support for CVS, SVN and BitKeeper would all be useful.
2. More important than support for a specific source control system is the ability to control the returned list myself.
3. An acceptable solution would also be to use a key-binding other than TAB. (ctrl- perhaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpage:

> the  *complete*  builtin command can be used to tell the shell how to complete words other than filenames, commands and variables

might get you started

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to program in tcsh. But if you can, then you could look at the file named "bash_completion" from the archive (find the download link [here](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/).)

On line 1673 begins CVS completion code - and this might be portable to csh if you are familiar with the differences between bash/tcsh.

On my ubuntu machine, there is also a section for SVN completion (in /etc/bash_completion) that doesn't seem to be present in the maintainer's archive.

Answer (score -2):

That's not Ubuntu-specific behavior, it's the [`bash-completion`](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/bash-completion/) project.

You could use that, if you can switch from tcsh to bash.